# mysql group by, right join. order not work

Tags: mysql

How to **sort** this query by messages date `DESC`. This return first row.

```
        SELECT 
            `u`.`username`, `u`.`id` AS `user_id`, `m`.`text`, `m`.`date`
        FROM
            `users` AS `u`
        RIGHT JOIN(
            SELECT
                `from`, `to`, `text`, `date`
            FROM
                `messages`
            WHERE
                (`from` = 6 OR `to` = 6)
        ) AS `m` ON (IF(`m`.`from` = 6, `m`.`to`, `m`.`from`) = `u`.`id`)

        GROUP BY
            `u`.`id`
            ORDER BY 
                `m`.`date` DESC
```

Comment: Why do you use GROUP BY since you don't do any aggregation? Explain what you want to do.

Comment: Note that no one ever uses RIGHT JOIN. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you sure you want a RIGHT JOIN? (Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.)

Comment: i need to select all users in chat and last message in every chat

Comment: Do you want all users with messages - do an INNER JOIN. Do you want all users, even without messages, do LEFT JOIN. Now, with this RIGHT JOIN, you want messages even without users.

Comment: inner join return same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is applied nearly last in the execution plan, after the `GROUP BY`.  The `ORDER BY` affects only the sequence of the returned rows, it does not influence which rows are returned.

The `GROUP BY` clause is causing groups of rows to be collapsed; the values returned for the `date` and `text` columns will come from *some* row in the group, but its not guaranteed to be the last row, or the first row, or any particular row.

A MySQL-specific (and non-standard) extension allows the query to execute and return result. We observe more ANSI-standards compatible behavior (throwing an error about non-aggregates in the SELECT list not in GROUP BY) similar to other RDBMS) when we include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in `sql_mode`.

---

To get the "latest" date for each `(from,to)` pair, where either `from` or `to` is 6, we can write a query like this:

```
  SELECT t.`from`
       , t.`to`
       , MAX(t.`date`) AS `date`
    FROM `messages` t
   WHERE t.`from` = 6
      OR t.`to`   = 6
   GROUP
      BY t.`from`
       , t.`to`
   ORDER
      BY ...
```

We can reference the result from that query, in another query, by referencing that as an inline view. (A "derived table", in the MySQL vernacular.)

We can join that to a the `messsages` table to retrieve the whole row, to get the value of the `text` column from that row.

Something like this:

```
  SELECT m.`from`
       , m.`to`
       , m.`date`
       , m.`text`
    FROM ( -- inline view to get latest date 
           SELECT t.`from`
                , t.`to`
                , MAX(t.`date`) AS `date`
             FROM `messages` t
            WHERE t.`from` = 6
               OR t.`to`   = 6
            GROUP
               BY t.`from`
                , t.`to`
         ) s
    JOIN `messages` m
      ON m.`from` = s.`from`
     AND m.`to`   = s.`to`
     AND m.`date` = s.`date`
   ORDER
      BY ...
```

(If the `(from,to,date)` tuple is not guaranteed to be unique, if there are multiple rows with the same latest `date`, for a given `from`/`to` pair, the query will return all of the matching rows.)

I think this addresses the crux of the problem, without involving a join to the `users` 
table.  But for completeness, we can demonstrate an outer join to `users` ...

```
  SELECT m.`from`
       , m.`to`
       , m.`date`
       , m.`text`

       , u.`username`
       , u.`id`

    FROM ( -- inline view to get latest date 
           SELECT t.`from`
                , t.`to`
                , MAX(t.`date`) AS `date`
             FROM `messages` t
            WHERE t.`from` = 6
               OR t.`to`   = 6
            GROUP
               BY t.`from`
                , t.`to`
         ) s
    JOIN `messages` m
      ON m.`from` = s.`from`
     AND m.`to`   = s.`to`
     AND m.`date` = s.`date`

   LEFT
   JOIN `users` u 
     ON u.id = CASE 6 WHEN m.`to` THEN m.`from` ELSE m.`to` END

   ORDER
      BY ...
```

---

NOTE:  This query pattern differentiates between `from` and `to`; the from/to pair `(6,42)` is seen as distinct from `(42,6)`.

If the goal is to handle those two as the same, we can modify that initial query. We could do something like this:

```
  SELECT IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`from` ,t.`to`  ) AS `from`
       , IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`to`   ,t.`from`) AS `to`
       , MAX(t.`date`) AS `date`
    FROM `messages` f
   WHERE t.`from` = 6
      OR t.`to`   = 6
   GROUP
      BY IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`from` ,t.`to`  )
       , IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`to`   ,t.`from`)
```

There other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. Whatever query we write to get the "latest" date for the from/to pairs, we can use that query as an inline view, to get the rows from `messages`.  With this inline view, the join to `messages` is complicated because we've swapped the "from" and "to" values, so the join to messages will need to check for pairs in both directions. (We need to try to match to "from/to" and "to/from")

```
  SELECT m.`from`
       , m.`to`
       , m.`date`
       , m.`text`
    FROM ( -- inline view to get latest date 
           SELECT IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`from` ,t.`to`  ) AS `from`
                , IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`to`   ,t.`from`) AS `to`
                , MAX(t.`date`) AS `date`
             FROM `messages` f
            WHERE t.`from` = 6
               OR t.`to`   = 6
            GROUP
               BY IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`from` ,t.`to`  )
                , IF(t.`from`=6 ,t.`to`   ,t.`from`)
         ) s
    JOIN `messages` m
      ON m.`date` = s.`date`
     AND ( 
            ( m.`from` = s.`from` AND m.`to`   = s.`to` ) 
         OR
            ( m.`to`   = s.`from` AND m.`from` = s.`to` )
         )
   ORDER
      BY ...
```

Comment: I did not expect such a detailed reply, thank you friend